# How to nest a variable in another variable for parameter passing?

Tags: bash, shell

say we have:

```
test() {
    echo $1
    echo $2
}
```

and two variables:

```
a="hello world"
b="$a blabla.."

test $b
```

it displays:

```
hello
world
```

what I want is:

```
hello world
blabla..
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a shell expert, but can't you just do echo $1, $2

Comment: @ArashSaidi if I do echo $1, $2 in test(), I get 'hello, world'. But What I want is 'hello world, blabla..'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
a="hello world"
b="'$a' blabla"
eval "test $b"
```

The single-quotes are needed to keep `hello world` together as a single argument. Then you need to use `eval` because quotes are not normally processed after variable expansion.

Comment: You should only use `eval` if your shell does not support arrays (for instance, you require POSIX compatibility).

Comment: It depends on where the values are coming from, and how they're being put together into the variable.

Comment: It seems that if you have the ability to control the format of `b`, you also have the ability to make `b` an array instead. I'm not sure what other situation would preclude the use of an array.

Answer (score 2):

You want `b` to be an array, otherwise there's no way with a single string containing whitespace to determine which space char is the separator:

```
mytest() {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
}

a="hello world"
b=( "$a" "blah blah" )

mytest "${b[@]}"
```

```
hello world
blah blah
```

Comment: A very interesting approach

Comment: +1 Also the correct approach, as this is why shells add support for arrays.